# Mobile and desktop display CSS background color

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to make a simple code for desktop and mobile display.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media (min-device-width: 770px) {
#containermobile {display:none;}
}
body {
background-color: #000000;
}
@media (max-device-width: 769px) {
#containerPC {display:none;}
}
body {
background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="containerPC">pc</div>
<div id="containermobile">mobile</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Yet the background color is not displaying. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put the `body` blocks inside the `@media` blocks, so the second one just overrides the first one, and you get white background.

Also, for the purpose of testing, you should probably avoid using `#000000` (black) and `#ffffff` (white). The former will hide the text, and the latter is the default background color so you can't be sure whether your code worked.

The following is an example of what will work correctly:

```
@media (min-device-width: 770px) {
    #containermobile {display:none;}
    body {
        background-color: #444444;
    }
}
@media (max-device-width: 769px) {
    #containerPC {display:none;}
    body {
        background-color: #cccccc;
    }
}
```